# Laravel Controller Web Route modification

Tags: jquery, laravel, controller

I want to put code from the web router to a controller because I think this would by the correct way to handle code in laravel. But Im not really sure how to do this. Here is my java script part which is in my view

```
<script>
    $('#spiele').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);

        var spielID = e.target.value;

        //ajax
        $.get('/spieler-table?spielID=' + spielID, function(data){

            //success data
            $('#A').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){
                $('#A').append('<option value="' + valueAusData.id + '">'+valueAusData.note+'</option>');


                $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr>')
                $('#myTable tr:last').after('<td>'+ valueAusData.note+'</td>')
                $('#myTable tr:last').after('<td>'+ valueAusData.note+'</td>')
                $('#myTable tr:last').after('</tr>')

                //$('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+ valueAusData.note+'</td></tr>')
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my router function at the moment

```
Route::get('/spieler-table', function(){
    $spielID = Input::get('spielID');
    $spielerOutput = Spieler::where('spielPlanID', '=', $spielID)->get();
    return Response::json($spielerOutput);
    //echo $spielerOutput;
});
```

And I want to put it via

```
Route::get('/spieler-table', 'SpielerController@getSpieler');
```

I did that but it will not work in the view. Im new with jQuery and at the moment I don't understand how the generate data via eloquent gets back to the view? Is it the return Responds::j son? But what exactly make responds::son and how can I put the function from web router into controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should do is place the exact same code in the `getSpieler` function of your `SpielerController` :

```
public function getSpieler()
{
    $spielID = Input::get('spielID');
    $spielerOutput = Spieler::where('spielPlanID', '=', $spielID)->get();
    return Response::json($spielerOutput);
}
```